# Auto zoom to polygons with agm core

Tags: agm-core

Is there any build in settings which can auto zoom to polygons? I have found that there is auto zoom to markers but it doesn't work with polygons.

[JSFiddle](https://stackblitz.com/edit/agm-polygon-tmlrqk?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't. you can create a pull request to add `fitBounds` to `agm-polygon`